# Обновить iOS-приложение, распространяемое вне App Store

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mac

Приложение распространяется через наш сайт. В данный момент пользователям приходится обновляться вручную. Хотим автоматизировать обновление.

В манифесте указан адрес обновлений. Пробовал прибавить к версии цифру в манифесте в Xcode. Не помогло.

Как обновить приложение в фоновом режиме?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю в фоновом режиме без участия пользователя, используя распространение OTA (over the air), это никак не сделать, можно немного облегчить жизнь, добавив в приложение проверку наличия обновления и добавив переход по ссылке в Сафари, где пользователь опять же вручную сможет нажать на ссылку для обновления приложения.